# Steganography Algorithm for Video using Jsteg or another simple algorithm .

Tags: mpeg, steganography

The Jsteg algorithm is basically a simple algorithm for steganography in JPEG images . It works on the following way -

1 -Calculate the DCT coefficients of every macro block ( a part of JPEG compression algorithm) 
and find the quantized matrix , so lets say the quantized matrix is the following :

[image: Quantized matrix]

now for every value that is not 1 , 0 , -1 , apply LSB .

My question was - that can i apply the same algorithm for MPEG videos as well just on the I-frames .

Please also do let me know if you have some other simple video steganography algorithm that i can use with MPEG videos .